# Does my model overfits or underfits based on the learning curves I obtain?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, training-data, overfitting-underfitting

I want to find a good fit for my data, so I started with training the basic model (for the simple binary classification problem) and plotted the learning curves from the training. The plot I got:

[Learning curves for training of my model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3VQd.png)

However, I am not sure what these curves mean, does the model overfit or underfit? Seems like there is a quite big gap between the training and validation curve, so I assumed it's overfitting and I added some regularization, however that seemed to only decrease both validation and test set accuracy and the gap remained more-less the same. So is this plot showing bias then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When *both curves* have reached a plateau, are *close and fairly high* then it's **underfitting**.

When *both curves are separated by substantial gap* and model performs significantly better on training data (*training curve is fairly low*) than on *validation curve (fairly high* in graph) then it's **overfitting**.

Ideally, **you'd want both curves to stay low in the graph and very close to each other with not much gap in between.**